# How to get last active node status preserved or selected as it was before on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have a `jstree` where i want to get the last **active** `node` to intact as it was before by saving last state in `localStorage`

**below image shows on page load i want to get the result:**

[image]

here is how i'm saving last state to `localStorage`

```
var lastClickedData = data.inst.get_json();
 localStorage.setItem('lastnode',JSON.stringify(lastClickedData));
```

here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Jg3B/2128/

```js
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree({
        "json_data" : {
            "data" : [
                {
                    "data" : "A node",
                    "metadata" : { id : 23 },
                    "children" : [ "Child 1", "A Child 2" ]
                },
                {
                    "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id1" },
                    "data" : {
                        "title" : "Long format demo",
                        "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
    });
    
 var highlightAndExpandLastActiveNode = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastnode'));
       // $('#jstree')  //set last acive node
       console.log(highlightAndExpandLastActiveNode);
    });


 $("#jstree").bind("select_node.jstree", function(evt, data) {

          if (data.inst._get_parent().length <= 0 || data.inst._get_parent() === -1){
            console.log('clicked data', data.inst.get_json());
          } else {
            var lastClickedData = data.inst.get_json();
            localStorage.setItem('lastnode',JSON.stringify(lastClickedData));
          }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://old.static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<div id="jstree">
</div>
```

please help me thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a newer version of jstree (v3.2.1). When you select a node in the tree and then reload the page, the node is selected again based on the node's id saved in localStorage.

http://jsfiddle.net/t4s7dz52/

javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('#jstree').jstree({
    'core': {
      'data': [{
          "text": "A node",
          "children": ["Child 1", "A Child 2"]
        },
        "Long format demo"
      ]
    }
  });

  $('#jstree').bind('loaded.jstree', function() {
    var selectedNodeId = localStorage.getItem('selectedNodeId');
    $('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node(selectedNodeId);
  });
});


$("#jstree").bind("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
  localStorage.setItem('selectedNodeId', data.node.id);
});
```

html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<div id="jstree">
</div>
```

Comment: `nodeid` will not change on each load of page or having 2 instances

Comment: By `nodeid` do you mean `selectedNodeId` stored in localStorage? I don't understand what you're saying. Your comment reads like a statement but I get the feeling you are saying something doesn't work the way you want it to. Can you please explain in more detail what you want? Also what do you mean by "2 instances"? Two instances of what?